# Find volume of methanol produced via reaction between carbon monoxide and hydrogen gases

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws, density

> Methanol is manufactured by the reaction of carbon monoxide gas with hydrogen gas. If a $95~\%$ yield is usually obtained, approximately how many liters of hydrogen gas at $\pu{350 °C}$ and $\pu{300 atm}$ are usually required to make $1.0$ liter of methanol measured at $\pu{20.0 °C}?$ The density of methanol at $\pu{20.0 °C}$ is $\pu{0.8 g mL^-1}.$
>
> (a) $\pu{0.89 L}$
> (b) $\pu{2.5 L}$
> (c) $\pu{4.8 L}$
> (d) $\pu{5.0 L}$
> (e) $\pu{8.1 L}$

> The correct answer is (d) $\pu{5.0 L}.$

I got two different answers, both wrong. I have detailed them below.

#### Attempt 1

I found the mass of methanol:

$$m(\ce{MeOH}) = \rho V = (\pu{0.8 g mL^-1})(\pu{1000 mL}) = \pu{800 g},\tag{1.1}$$

and calculated its theoretical yield:

$$m_\mathrm{theor}(\ce{MeOH}) = 0.95\times\pu{800 g} = \pu{842 g}.\tag{1.2}$$

The amount of methanol is

$$n(\ce{MeOH}) = \frac{\pu{842 g}}{\pu{32 g mol^-1}} = \pu{26.3 mol}.\tag{1.3}$$

The amount of hydrogen from balanced equation is $n(\ce{H2}) = \pu{52.6 mol}.$ From here

$$
\begin{align}
V(\ce{H2}) &= \frac{nRT}{p} \\
  &= \frac{(\pu{52.6 mol})(\pu{8.31 J mol^-1 K^-1})(\pu{(350 + 273) K})}{\pu{3E7 Pa}} \\
  &= \pu{9.08E-3 m^3} \\
  &\approx \pu{9.1 L}. \tag{1.4}
\end{align}
$$

#### Attempt 2

Assuming the pressure of methanol is $\pu{1 atm} = \pu{1E5 Pa},$

$$
\begin{align}
n &= \frac{pV}{RT} \\
  &= \frac{(\pu{1E5 Pa})(\pu{1000 mL})}{(\pu{8.31 J mol^-1 K^-1})(\pu{293 K})} \\
  &= \pu{41071 mol}. \tag{2.1}
\end{align}
$$

Theoretical amount of methanol is

$$n_\mathrm{theor}(\ce{MeOH}) = \pu{41071 mol}/0.95 = \pu{43232 mol}.\tag{2.2}$$

The amount of hydrogen from the balanced equation is $n(\ce{H2}) = \pu{86464 mol}.$ From here

$$
\begin{align}
V(\ce{H2}) &= \frac{nRT}{p} \\
  &= \frac{(\pu{86464 mol})(\pu{8.31 J mol^-1 K^-1})(\pu{(350 + 273) K})}{\pu{3E7 Pa}} \\
  &= \pu{14.92 m^3}. \tag{2.3}
\end{align}
$$

Attempt 2 is definitely wrong. I don't get what I did wrong in my attempt 1. What am I missing?

Comment: It is always good to summarize and/or complement the verbal description by algebra. 

Good practice is starting with symbolic algebraic expressions and keeping it this way until all is ready to plug in literal numbers. It helps in focusing on principles, mistakes are easier to spot, orientation is improved, Q/A is reusable and has bigger  permanent value. 

You may find useful  [formatting mathematical/chemical expressions/formulas](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here/88).

Comment: If the correct answer is d) the volume of methanol is 5 L not 5mL. And that is the volume of the *liquid* so no calculations using the gas equation are relevant to it.

Comment: @matt_black It is volume of pressurized (300 atm) hydrogen, not methanol.

Comment: @Poutnik The wording for attempt 2 says "Assuming the pressure of methanol is 1 atm" so maybe it is careless wording, but sounds wrong.

Comment: @matt_black Take the bold text.  **approximately how many liters of hydrogen gas at 350 °C and 300 atm**

Comment: @Natalie  Methanol at 20 deg C is liquid, not gas, and you cannot use for it the ideal gas state equation. (attempt 2 )

Comment: @matt_black Yeah sorry it should be 5 L

Comment: @Poutnik Yeah my attempt 2 is definitely wrong, couldn't think of anything else though. I don't really get why attempt 1 is wrong. What am I missing?

Comment: I think the yield has units of mols per mol (i.e. actual moles per theoretical moles is 0.95), not grams per gram.  I don't think it makes a difference numerically but it'd be cleaner to convert to moles first, then adjust for yield.

Comment: Your first calculation was right. The volume of $\ce{H2}$ must be nearly $9$ L, and not nearly $5$ L. $5$ L is not far from the expected volume of $\ce{CO}$.

Comment: @Karl This question is from a past paper of a Chemistry Olympiad test. You’re right I don’t think they considered how practical this question is.

Comment: @CurtF. What do you mean? I used density=mass/volume to find the mass of methanol and I used that mass in the yield calculation

Comment: @Maurice I thought it might be an error in the mark scheme but 9.1 L is not even one of the MCQ options so it couldn’t have been a typo. Like I mentioned earlier it’s from a past preliminary Olympiad test. Usually the questions are fully vetted. I really want confirm that it’s an error in the question and my answer is right before getting back to the student who asked me this.

Comment: I have evaluated the attempt 1 some time ago and it does seem to me to be an error in the task formulation or answer list preparation. If we considered hydrogen as a real gas at this high pressure, the resulting volume would be even higher.

Comment: @Karl I really don't understand the criticism of the question. Surely students should learn to calculate yield via stoichiometry? It's not a fictional process: "The industrial production of synthetic methanol abroad has been known for some time and in May, 1927, an industrial production of 4500 gallons of methanol daily was announced by one American company. In this instance, carbon dioxide and hydrogen, hitherto waste gases from the production of butanol and acetone from corn, were utilized." [Methanol from Hydrogen and Carbon Monoxide, 1928](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ie50225a025)